# how to do a linear transformation in excel?

Tags: excel

I need some help making a linear transformation in excel please.

High number in range - 1800, transformed to 100
Low number in range - 2, transformed to 1

y=a+b⋅x
x is the original value
y is the transformed value

1800 has to become 100. Thus the first equation then is 100=a+b⋅1800.

2 has to become 1. The second equation is 1=a+b⋅2.

Now we can use this to equations two calculate the values of a and b.

Using this equation the original value of 723 will be transformed to the value of 40.70.

How do I do this in excel?

Comment: Select the range of cells with the starting number in the first cell and the end number in the last cell. Choose Home ► Editing ► Fill ► Series ► OK (the *Step value* should be calculated for you).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Thanks for introducing me to the fill function though.

I want 
1800 1700 1300 723 400 200 20 2

To become something like
100 90 85 40 20 10 2 1

Just estimates

Comment: What you are describing is nothing more than pre-algebra maths (ratio/fraction/percentage of a whole) and **not** a programming question.

Comment: Excel doesn't have a built-in function for this, so you'll need to write a macro (VBA code) to do this

Comment: Please don't be angry Jeeped. We're all at different levels of understanding.

Comment: I'm looking for the VBA code to do this Mark.

Comment: Well, what have you tried.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  If you have code please post it in your original post and tell us what it specifically is doing that is in error.  We will then do or best to help over come the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could further simplify the formula given by Axel if you allow a few extra fields on your table. To make things easier to read, I usually give these fields names (using `<cntrl-F3>`) like "min", "max", "a" and "b". The table then looks as simple as this:

```
    [A]     [B]         [c] [D]        // showing the formulae ...
[1]  min    =MIN(A:A)   a   =1-min*b
[2]  max    =MAX(A:A)   b   =99/(max-min)
[3]  1800   =a+b*A3     
[4]  1700   =a+b*A4     
[5]  1300   =a+b*A5     
[6]  723    =a+b*A6     
[7]  400    =a+b*A7     
[8]  200    =a+b*A8     
[9]  20     =a+b*A9     
[10] 2      =a+b*A10
```

Or, showing the actual values, you would get:

```
    [A]     [B]         [c] [D]        // showing the values ...
[1]  min    =2          a   =0.889877642
[2]  max    =1800       b   =0.055061179
[3]  1800   =100    
[4]  1700   =94.49388209    
[5]  1300   =72.46941046    
[6]  723    =40.69911012    
[7]  400    =22.91434928    
[8]  200    =11.90211346    
[9]  20     =1.991101224    
[10] 2      =1
```

Comment: i'm launching an online business and i could use your services for small problems that may come up from time to time. if you are interested in doing some paid consulting for me, email me : sanbackups@gmail.com! Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 1):

Your equations will not be the right ones for linear functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function_(calculus): the basic equation is `f(x) = ax + b`.

So the `a` and `b` in your example can be calculated as shown in my picture:

[image]

Then getting the special example to universally applicable will lead to the formula in `B1` downwards:

```
=((MAX(A:A)/MIN(A:A)-100)/(MAX(A:A)/MIN(A:A)-1)-1)/-MIN(A:A)*A1+(MAX(A:A)/MIN(A:A)-100)/(MAX(A:A)/MIN(A:A)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Axel! You helped a lot!